# Pause YouTube video on background Ionic

Tags: android, video, ionic-framework, youtube

Well, my Android app was rejected, for this reason:

> it because it violates our device and network abuse policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.
>
> 1. Modify your app to make sure it doesn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service; for example, **by enabling background play of YouTube videos.**

I followed this tutorial to create and display my YouTube feed:

https://github.com/hughred22/YouTube-Video-Listing-Ionic-Mobile-App/wiki/Step-by-Step-Tutorial

```
    .controller('videoCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.videos = [];

    //YouTube API settings for main video page
    $scope.youtubeParams = {
      key: 'AIzaSyDquqHEMvVJ1qmI3_17cTs_jdakjshdka',
      type: 'video',
      maxResults: '5',
      part: 'id,snippet',
      //q: 'creatorup',
      order: 'date',
      channelId: 'UCll2vOerYsQ02RwzD2Uwjhhj',
    }

    $scope.playerVars = {
      rel: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      modestbranding: 0,
    }    

    $scope.$on('youtube.player.ready', function ($event, player) {
      $rootScope.YTPlayer = player;
    });

    //document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
      //if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
      //$rootScope.YTPlayer.stopVideo();
      //$rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
      //}
    //}, false);

    //$scope.$on('youtube.player.paused', function ($event, player) {
      //if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
        //player.pauseVideo();
        //$rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
      //}
    //});

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
      if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
      //$rootScope.YTPlayer.stopVideo();
      $rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
      }
    });   

    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {params:$scope.youtubeParams}).success(function(response){
      angular.forEach(response.items, function(child){
        //console.log (child);
        $scope.videos.push(child);
      });
    });
  })
```

As you can see here are the variations that I am using to listen for a webview leave:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
  if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
  $rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
  }
}, false);

$scope.$on('youtube.player.paused', function ($event, player) {
  if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
    $rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
  }
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
  if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
  //$rootScope.YTPlayer.stopVideo();
  $rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
  }
});
```

No matter what I use I cannot get the video to pause when the app is in the background. I have seen a couple of threads on this but none have been helpful. Thanks!